# Always jumping position at the selected item of horizontal recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I would like to create a custom horizonal recycler view which support either scroll by user or click to snap selected item to center.

After the item is selected, especially last 3 items or new items loaded, the selected view holder jumps.

Please tell me the way to make padding not jumpy

Below is my code.

```
import android.content.Context
import android.view.View
import androidx.core.view.updatePaddingRelative
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Recycler
import kotlin.math.abs

class CenterZoomLayoutManager : LinearLayoutManager {
    private val mShrinkAmount = 0.15f
    private val mShrinkDistance = 0.9f


    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView

    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context) {}

    override fun scrollVerticallyBy(dy: Int, recycler: Recycler, state: RecyclerView.State): Int {
        val orientation = orientation
        return if (orientation == VERTICAL) {
            val scrolled = super.scrollVerticallyBy(dy, recycler, state)
            val midpoint = height / 2f
            val d0 = 0f
            val d1 = mShrinkDistance * midpoint
            val s0 = 1f
            val s1 = 1f - mShrinkAmount
            for (i in 0 until childCount) {
                val child = getChildAt(i) ?: continue
                val childMidpoint = (getDecoratedBottom(child) + getDecoratedTop(child)) / 2f
                val d = d1.coerceAtMost(abs(midpoint - childMidpoint))
                val scale = s0 + (s1 - s0) * (d - d0) / (d1 - d0)
                val modifiedScale  = if (child.isSelected) 1.0f else 0.9f
                child.scaleX = modifiedScale
                child.scaleY = modifiedScale
            }
            scrolled
        } else {
            0
        }
    }

    override fun scrollHorizontallyBy(dx: Int, recycler: Recycler, state: RecyclerView.State): Int {
        val orientation = orientation
        return if (orientation == HORIZONTAL) {
            val scrolled = super.scrollHorizontallyBy(dx, recycler, state)
            scrolled
        } else {
            0
        }
    }


    override fun onLayoutChildren(recycler: RecyclerView.Recycler, state: RecyclerView.State) {
        // always measure first item, its size determines starting offset
        // this must be done before super.onLayoutChildren
        if (childCount == 0 && state.itemCount > 0) {
            val firstChild = recycler.getViewForPosition(0)
            measureChildWithMargins(firstChild, 0, 0)
            recycler.recycleView(firstChild)
        }
        super.onLayoutChildren(recycler, state)
    }

    override fun measureChildWithMargins(child: View, widthUsed: Int, heightUsed: Int) {
        val lp = (child.layoutParams as RecyclerView.LayoutParams).absoluteAdapterPosition
        super.measureChildWithMargins(child, widthUsed, heightUsed)
        if (lp != 0 && lp != itemCount - 1) return
        // after determining first and/or last items size use it to alter host padding
        when (orientation) {
            RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL -> {
                val hPadding = ((width - child.measuredWidth) / 2).coerceAtLeast(0)
                if (!reverseLayout) {
                    if (lp == 0) recyclerView.updatePaddingRelative(start = hPadding)
                    if (lp == itemCount - 1) recyclerView.updatePaddingRelative(end = hPadding)
                } else {
                    if (lp == 0) recyclerView.updatePaddingRelative(end = hPadding)
                    if (lp == itemCount - 1) recyclerView.updatePaddingRelative(start = hPadding)
                }
            } else  -> {

            }
        }
    }

    // capture host recyclerview
    override fun onAttachedToWindow(view: RecyclerView) {
        recyclerView = view
        super.onAttachedToWindow(view)
    }
}
```